# ASP.NET MVC regular expression for comma separated strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to do MVC unobtrusive client side validation using regular expression in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

Valid Input is comma separated string values, for example: string1, string2, string 3 etc.

I tried below regEx pattern for comma separated strings but it's not working as expected. Could anyone tell me what's wrong in below expression ?

```
[RegularExpression(@"/^[a-zA-Z]{1,20},[a-zA-Z]{1,20}$/",
                        ErrorMessage = "Please enter comma separated list")]
    public string SettingOptions { get; set; }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to enforce the number used should only be in range 1 to 20?

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your example string1, string2, string 3 etc:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+$


[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+$"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
"[a-zA-Z]{1,20},[a-zA-Z]{1,20}"
```

Because `^` and `$` denotes the starting and ending of string.
It will allow only `string1,string2`.

Comment: This only matches on two comma seperated strings. Not 3 as the example states.

Comment: yes but as I stated.. Only two not more not less, also spaces will not be possible between the seperated values.

Answer (score 0):

To match your regex against a comma separated string would use a regex such as:

`[0-9a-zA-Z]+(,[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*`

If you wish to remove the numbers then you can drop the 0-9 requirement.

After more review there could be small discrepancies with this regex and came up with an alternative that may be more helpful. The previous regex would not allow for spaces in each separated string item.

`^([a-zA-Z0-9]+,?\s*)+$`